Spivak Calculus on Manifolds Problem 4-30
spivak CoM exercise 4-30
could someone help me understand the hint?
If I assume $w = \lambda d \theta + dg$ then $\int{c{R,1}} w = 2 \pi \lambda$. So the hint suggests I should integrate over $[0,1]$ to show all $\lambda_R$ are equal. However when i integrate the hint on $[0,1]$ i get $\lambda_R + g_R(1) - g_R(0)$ and don't see how to proceed from here. I also don't understand how we can write $c_{R,1}^*(w) = \lambda_R dx + d(g_R)$ for some $\lambda_R \in \mathbb R$ and $g: \mathbb R^2 - 0 \to \mathbb R$. Maybe such $\lambda_R$ and $g$ don't exist for some $R$?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
